# ListView selecting more then one item

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I've a problem with listview in android, I've created a list view that takes data from SQLite database with a custom ArrayAdapter
I want to display an image view when user choose an item, but when I click on an item, the image (check mark) shows in 3 other items
I don't know where is the problem exactly, here is my code for adapter :

```
import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.R;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.itdinamik.tabswipe.CompareVehicle;
import com.itdinamik.vcompare.MySQLiteHelper;
import com.itdinamik.vcompare.Vehicle;

public class ComperAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Vehicle>{

List<Vehicle>   data;
Context context;
int layoutResID;
Vehicle itemdata;
MySQLiteHelper dbhelper;

public ComperAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Vehicle> data) {

super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
this.data=data;
this.context=context;
this.layoutResID=layoutResourceId;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
final NewsHolder holder;
View row = convertView;

dbhelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);

if(row == null)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    row = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, parent, false);

    holder = new NewsHolder();

    holder.itemNameTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.VehicleTxt);
    holder.itemNameScore = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.Score);
    holder.CheckedMark=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.Checked);
    holder.Vehicle=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.Vehicle);
    holder.RL = (RelativeLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.Rv);

    row.setTag(holder);
}
else
{
    holder = (NewsHolder)row.getTag();
}

//Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(position +" - " + CompareVehicle.ClickedItem),               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
if(CompareVehicle.ItemClieckd) {
 if(position == CompareVehicle.ClickedItem) {
     Log.w("Position", String.valueOf(position));
     holder.CheckedMark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     holder.RL.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(201, 50, 39));
 }

}
itemdata = data.get(position);
holder.itemNameTitle.setText(itemdata.getTitle() + " - " + itemdata.getKraj() + " - "+ String.valueOf(position) + " - " + CompareVehicle.ClickedItem);

double totaldefault = itemdata.getOhranjenost()*0.25+itemdata.getPrevozeni()*0.16+
        itemdata.getServis()*0.14+ itemdata.getCena()*0.13+
        itemdata.getPoraba()*0.11+ itemdata.getStarost()*0.08+
        itemdata.getDodatna()*0.07+ itemdata.getCenaZav()*0.06;

holder.itemNameScore.setText(String.format("%.1f",totaldefault));

return row;
}

static class NewsHolder{

TextView itemNameTitle;
TextView itemNameScore;
ImageView CheckedMark, Vehicle;
RelativeLayout RL;
}

}
```

and this one is for my fragment that i use to show my list view

```
import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.itdinamik.tabswipe.adapter.ComperAdapter;
import com.itdinamik.vcompare.MySQLiteHelper;
import com.itdinamik.vcompare.Vehicle;

public class CompareVehicle extends Fragment{
ViewPager mViewPager;
ArrayList<Vehicle>  DataList;
static MySQLiteHelper dbhelper;

ComperAdapter adapter;
List<Vehicle> itemData;


ListView lv;
Button CompareButton;

int ClickedNum = 0;
public static int ClickedItem;
public static boolean ItemClieckd = false;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_compare_vehicle, container, false);
    lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.CompareList);
    CompareButton = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.CompareButton);

     dbhelper = new MySQLiteHelper(getActivity());

    // get all vehicles
     itemData = dbhelper.getAllVehicles();

     adapter=new ComperAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.list_single,itemData);
     lv.setAdapter(adapter);

     lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ClickedItem = position;
            ItemClieckd = true;
            ClickedNum += 1;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            /*RelativeLayout Rl = (RelativeLayout)arg1.findViewById(R.id.Rv);
            ImageView CheckImg = (ImageView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.Checked);
            Rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(201, 50, 39));
            CheckImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);*/

            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(mSelectedItem), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });


     CompareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (ClickedNum < 2) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please mark at least 2 items to compare them", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });


    return rootView;
}

}
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid issues with view recycling in `ListViews` etc, I include a `boolean` for checked state in the item data `List` supplied to the constructor of the `ArrayAdapter`. I also provide my own `interface` for handling things like click events on child `Views` contained in my custom list item layout.

In my example below we handle a checkbox which can be clicked and also a label which can be long clicked:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyItem> {

    // interface for handling item child view events
    public interface MyListAdapterListener {
        void onItemCheckClicked(int index);
        void onItemLabelLongClicked(int index);        
    }

    private MyListAdapterListener mMyListAdapterListener;
    int layoutResID;

    // Constructor
    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<MyItem> myItems) {
        super(context, resource, myItems);
        layoutResID = resource;
    }

    public void setMyListAdapterListener(MyListAdapterListener listener) {
        this.mMyListAdapterListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // setup the row
        View row;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, null);
        } else {
            row = convertView;
        }

        // setup the ViewHolder for this item
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        if (holder == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }

        // setup this item's label view
        holder.label.setText(getItem(position).label);
        // tag this item's label view with position so it can be retrieved in the onLongClick
        holder.label.setTag(position);
        // set the OnLongClickListener for the this item's label view 
        holder.label.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                if (mActivityListListener != null) {
                // retrieve position from the view's tag, and trigger the listeners onItemLabelLongClicked method
                    mActivityListListener.onItemLabelLongClicked((Integer)v.getTag());
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        // setup this item's checkbox view
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(getItem(position).myItemCheckBoolean);
        // tag this item's checkbox view with position so it can be retrieved in the onClick
        holder.checkbox.setTag(position);
        // set the OnClickListener for the this item's checkbox view 
        holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mMyListAdapterListener != null) {
                    // retrieve position from the view's tag, and trigger the listeners onItemCheckClicked method
                    mMyListAdapterListener.onItemCheckClicked((Integer) v.getTag());
                }                    
            }
        });

        return row;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        CheckBox checkbox = null;
        TextView label = null;

        ViewHolder(View row) {
            this.checkbox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.check_box);
            this.label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_label);
        }
    }
}
```

The `MyItem` class:

```
public class MyItem {
    public String label;
    public boolean myItemCheckBoolean;
}
```

Using the `ArrayAdapter`:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
....
private List<MyItem> myItems = new ArrayList<MyItem>();
....
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__my_list, container, false);
    lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_list);

    // For example purposes, fill myItems with dummy data setting all checkboxes initially to false
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        MyItem myItem = new MyItem();
        myItem.label = "Item " + i;
        myItem.myItemCheckBoolean = false;
        myItems.add(myItem);
    }

    MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.my_list_item, myItems);
    adapter.setMyListAdapterListener( new MyListAdapter.MyListAdapterListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemCheckClicked(int index) {
            Log.d("MyFragment", "Item " + index + " Check Clicked");
            // toggle the item's boolean
            myItems.get(index).myItemCheckBoolean = !myItems.get(index).myItemCheckBoolean;
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemLabelLongClicked(int index) {
            Log.d("MyFragment", "Item " + index + " Label LongClicked");
        }

    }

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    ....
    return rootView;
}
```

---

**Additional:**
In response to your comment, you can use the adapter to customize the display of your list items as you wish. The version below shows how you might modify the adapter to use an ImageView instead of a CheckBox, and also changes the background color:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyItem> {

    // interface for handling item child view events
    public interface MyListAdapterListener {
        void onItemCheckClicked(int index);
        void onItemLabelLongClicked(int index);        
    }

    private MyListAdapterListener mMyListAdapterListener;
    int layoutResID;

    // Constructor
    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<MyItem> myItems) {
        super(context, resource, myItems);
        layoutResID = resource;
    }

    public void setMyListAdapterListener(MyListAdapterListener listener) {
        this.mMyListAdapterListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // setup the row
        View row;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, null);
        } else {
            row = convertView;
        }

        // setup the ViewHolder for this item
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        if (holder == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }

        // setup this item's label view
        holder.label.setText(getItem(position).label);
        // tag this item's label view with position so it can be retrieved in the onLongClick
        holder.label.setTag(position);
        // set the OnLongClickListener for the this item's label view 
        holder.label.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                if (mActivityListListener != null) {
                // retrieve position from the view's tag, and trigger the listeners onItemLabelLongClicked method
                    mActivityListListener.onItemLabelLongClicked((Integer)v.getTag());
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        // setup this item's image view based on the current state of the boolean
        if (getItem(position).myItemCheckBoolean) {
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_a);
        } else {
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_b);
        }
        // tag this item's image view with position so it can be retrieved in the onClick
        holder.image.setTag(position);
        // set the OnClickListener for the this item's image view 
        holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mMyListAdapterListener != null) {
                    // retrieve position from the view's tag, and trigger the listeners onItemCheckClicked method
                    mMyListAdapterListener.onItemCheckClicked((Integer) v.getTag());
                }                    
            }
        });

        // setup this item's background based on the current state of the boolean
        if (getItem(position).myItemCheckBoolean) {
            holder.layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.red);
        } else {
            holder.layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.white);
        }

        return row;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView image = null;
        TextView label = null;
        RelativeLayout layout = null;

        // constructor
        ViewHolder(View row) {
            this.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            this.label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_label);
            this.layout = (RelativeLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.item_layout)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, I will try this and let you know if it works or not

Comment: No problem. I have used this approach many times. If you have any specific issues implementing it, update your question with the details and I will try to assist.

Comment: thanks, can you please show me how i can do it with image instead of checkbox? and changing background color too